# EJBs always have to run inside a transaction?

Tags: spring, ejb

Hy,

I have read that EJBs always have to run inside a transaction, is this true? I mean,why cant I use the ejb container to inject a dependency in some bean like spring but without transtional environment?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By default EJB's always use transactions but you can mark the bean or more the specific each method not to use transactions using annotation `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NEVER)`.